# Run python file as admin

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a program that ask the user link of any websites to block it (in hosts)

```
import requests
print('Time to block some websites')
ask = input('> Give me the link... ') ; link = {} # Ask user
try:
    r = requests.get(ask) # Try the url 
    print('Protocol : ' , r.url [:r.url.find(":")]) # Check protocol of the url
    url = r.url 
    print('your url : ' , url)
except:
    raise ValueError('Give the url with https/http', ask)

url = url.split('/') ; urlist = list(url) # Split url 
link.update({'linko': urlist[2]}) ; link.update({'host': '127.0.0.1 '}) # Add host and url to link
x = link['linko'] ; y = link['host'] # Transform value of dict in string
z = str(y+x) # Assign host and link

f = open('hosts', 'a') # Open document in append mode
f.write(z) ; f.write('\n') # Write z and newline for future use
f.close() # Always close after use

f = open('hosts' , 'r') # Open document in read mode
print(f.read()) # Read document
f.close() # Always close after use
```

Traceback :

```
  File "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\block.py", line 17, in <module>
    f = open('hosts', 'a') # Open document in append mode
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'hosts'
```

When I tried to execute the program with runas administrator :

```
RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run - C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\block.py
193: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\block.py is not a valid Win32 application.
```

How do I get the program to have permissions to add sites to hosts?

Comment: I sounds like you forgot to specify `python` when using `runas`.

Comment: I dont think it is a administrator issue. The hosts file is usually read-only, so you should reset the read-only attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers, I found a 'manually' solution :

Running cmd.exe as admin then move to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc and execute block.py
Command prompt :

```
C:\Windows\system32>cd drivers

C:\Windows\System32\drivers>cd etc

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc>python block.py
Time to block some websites
> Give me the link... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64506935/run-python-file-as-admin
Protocol :  https
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64506935/run-python-file-as-admin
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#       127.0.0.1       localhost
#       ::1             localhost
127.0.0.1 stackoverflow.com

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc>
```